# Parse.com mobile registration verification

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

When I use parse.com, I am not sure whether there a module for Mobile registration, it will use my mobile number and a sms verification coder, the way just like like WhatsApp does?

Comment: Please let me know how to use Parse.com to fulfil the feature like WhatsApp does by installing an app without using user name and password, just by using the mobile number and the sms verification code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Parse has a service like that.

Nexmo, where I work, has an API that enables you to easily verify that a user has access to a specific mobile device. Nexmo sends a single use code by SMS or Voice, retrying when needed. Once the user enters the code to your app/website, the Verify API confirms if it is valid.

**Nexmo’s Verify API**

1. Make a call to https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json (or /xml)
2. Add parameters: api_key, api_secret, number (to be verified), & brand/app name
3. Optional parameters: language, length, etc. (Full list of parameters in documentation)

Take a look at the Nexmo's Verify documentation [here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify)

Comment: Thanks, is it free to use for Mobile verification?

Comment: No it's not but if you're looking for a free option, you won't have the most of the features and definitely not the reliability as a paid API such as Nexmo. The Verify API has a low flat rate **PER VERIFICATION** not per attempt.

Comment: Thanks,  I found this, but I don't know how to calculate the price.   http://blog.parse.com/announcements/phone-based-login-can-you-dig-it/

Comment: So in this example they're using Parse and Twilio. As an alternative to Twilio, you can use Nexmo. Here are the list of pricing for all the APIs Nexmo has to offer: https://www.nexmo.com/pricing/

I would suggest using the Verify SDK, if you just trying to verify users. Nexmo's Verify enables you to easily verify that a user has access to a specific mobile device. Nexmo sends a single use code by SMS or Voice, retrying when needed. Once the user returns the code to your app or website, the Verify API confirms that the code is valid.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why it charges monthly per mobile user, it uses the verification just once during the installation of the App.

Comment: Once again, if you are just trying to verify users, I would highly suggest using Nexmo's Verify SDK. There is no monthly charge whatsoever. There is a flat rate **per successful verification** not per attempt.